# What is a formal word for 'coming weeks'?

Tags: sentence-construction, formality

Is there a way to write this sentence more formally?

> I will follow up with you to discuss my research work in the coming weeks.

How can I replace the phrase 'coming weeks'?

Comment: the coming weeks is a standard phrase. It is not informal.

Comment: The only improvement that could be made is to be more specific. "coming weeks" is vague.'

Comment: Did you look up the word *coming*? What did you find?

Comment: Not the downvoter either, but the fact that OP views this question and answer as mostly helpful to non-native speakers suggests it is a better fit for English Language Learners SE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Coming weeks" is already formal, but if you really want an alternative:

> I will follow up with you to discuss my research work in the **next few weeks**.

Comment: +1 I don't see an issue of formality here. But I do think that "coming weeks" simply doesn't fit particularly well. It's not grammatically wrong, but its vagueness means I just wouldn't use it in this context. Your "next few weeks" or "a few weeks" would be my preference.